# allow access to only particular folder via USB on android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i want that only particular folders can be accessed via the USB connection to the computer.
Basically i want to give access to only the images and videos and notes that are stored on the android tablet.
This is for samsung galaxy tab 2 running 4.0.3

Is their some app to do that or how can it be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are not allowed to control, limit or stop access to the external storage on a device for security reasons.

You will have to modify Android at the firmware level to do this.